# Call a function that triggers a service call on every state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a group of check boxes that filter the data. After the initial data is rendered and as I'm dealing with charts, I want to make the UX dynamic. Therefore, for every state change in my react component, I want to call a function that triggers a service.

```
handleChange = (query) => {
    if(this.state.initialSearchTriggered) {
    this.setState({query})
    this.triggerReportsService()
  }
}
```

Now the problem is, react takes time to update the state, and the `triggerReportsService` uses `this.state.query` to call the service. Therefore, the service query parameter does not have the latest filters. Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking to add `componentDidUpdate()` method but service calls are getting called multiple times than expected.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   this.state.initialSearchTriggered ? this.triggerReportsService() : null;
}
```

Please help

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a callback to your setState function.  The callback will fire when the state update is complete.

```
handleChange = (query) => {
    if(this.state.initialSearchTriggered) {
    this.setState({query}, this.triggerReportsService)
  }
}
```